# Gitlab+Jenkins through webhook it shows this error, how can I solve this?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

Hook executed successfully but returned HTTP 403:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>URI:</th>
            <td>/job/pipeline3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>STATUS:</th>
            <td>403</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>MESSAGE:</th>
            <td>No valid crumb was included in the request</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>SERVLET:</th>
            <td>Stapler</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.27.v20200227</a>
    <hr/> </body>

</html>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILkVD.png)

Comment: In exactly which operation returns this error?

Comment: in testing webhook.

Comment: had the same issue but with github did you resolve this @JamZey ?

Comment: For me the URL for webhook what I saw was wrong. It was ```https://JENKINS_URL/job/YOUR_JOB``` it should be ```https://JENKINS_URL/project/YOUR_JOB```, changing the ```job``` to ```project``` solved my issue

Comment: @eemilk this worked perfectly for me