# HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request error with GitLab+Jenkins on windows environment

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I know the similar question has been asked many time before. I am trying to integarte GitLab with Jenkins through webhook and have an error as mentioned in title. I found the answer as well as per my situation which is listed here

[Gitlab+Jenkins through webhook it shows this error, how can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60807674/gitlabjenkins-through-webhook-it-shows-this-error-how-can-i-solve-this/72603719#72603719).

The thing which is not understanable for me right now is as per the suggested solution

> For me the URL for webhook what I saw was wrong. It was https://JENKINS_URL/job/YOUR_JOB it should be https://JENKINS_URL/project/YOUR_JOB, changing the job to project solved my issue

I am not able to find a way that how I can change job URL from https://JENKINS_URL/**job**/YOUR_JOB to https://JENKINS_URL/**project**/YOUR_JOB within Jenkins to build job URL as per GitLab webhook settings.

Any help will  be much appreciated. Thanks

Update - My Jenkins server is configured with URL http://JENKINS_URL:8080/

Comment: Are you working on localhost? and also are you using the public GitLab or using an organization GitLab

Comment: @Affes Salem - not working with localhost, Using Jenkins URL which is set in Jenkins Location. also using an organization GitLab npot public one.

Answer (score 0):

trying

1. login to jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System

in here, config your server jenkins
[image]

after back to Dashboard > New Item > Freestyle project.
In Build Triggers, select Build when a change is pushed to GitLab. GitLab webhook URL: X
[image]

after Advanced > Secret Token > Generate. you have key Y

2. login to gitlab, open your project.
   in your project click Settings choose Webhooks.
   paste X, Y in your config jenkins to here.
   [image]

click Test if gitlab noti:
[image]

you are success!!!

Comment: Thanks @Kiu Kiu Duck Pea - I know the procedure how to configure the web hook, the only problem is with job URL. Somehow I need to change/cofigure job URL's like http://JENKINS_URL/project/YOUR_JOB insted of http://JENKINS_URL/job/YOUR_JOB.

Comment: in jenkins, url hook gitlab is default  JENKINS_URL/project/YOUR_JOB, if you want override or instead Hook URL. you can try with github.

Comment: @ZahidAsim do you have a reverse proxy or a Loadbalancer in front of Jenkins?

Comment: @ycr - no reverse proxy or load balancer in my setup.

Comment: https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitlab-plugin/#plugin-content-webhook-url

Comment: @Kiu Kiu Duck Pea
I can't use github, have to setup with GitLab only. Please suggest if you know how to setup job URL in Jenkins as JENKINS_URL/**project**/YOUR_JOB instead of JENKINS_URL/**job**/YOUR_JOB?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reconfigure your Jenkins instance. What you should do is the following:

1. Go to the Jenkins project you want to use;
2. Go to `Configure` -> `Build triggers` section;
3. See the name of the checkbox `Build when a change is pushed to GitLab. GitLab webhook URL: <TARGET URL>`

What you're looking for is the "TARGET URL" from step 3. See the screenshot for an example of such an URL. As you can see it has the needed **project** format:
[image]